# JS library load via $.getScript generates Uncaught ReferenceError for PDFmake function

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript, pdfmake

I try to load pdfmake-browserified.min.js on a website running:

```
$.getScript('http://powercle.linuxpl.eu/js/pdfmake-browserified.min.js');
```

And it works in very simple test pages. But when I use it on more complex (real life) sites it loads OK but then it's like the library is not there as running createPdf function results in the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createPdf is not defined

As if the pdfmake library was never loaded. Simple test to replicate the issue:

1. Open http://powercle.linuxpl.eu/js/pdfmake_browserified4.html which is not loading the pdfmake
2. Open Console in your browser
3. Run createPdf command to get the ReferenceError (as expected)
4. Run the $.getScript('http://powercle.linuxpl.eu/js/pdfmake-browserified.min.js');
5. Run the createPdf command again and it will show the function is defined
6. All good! It works here, I can click [Open PDF] button and generate the PDF.

Next, open e.g. onet.pl website and do steps 2-5. You will get ReferenceError on the step 5. Why??! How do I fix it?

Comment: How you are using `createPdf`? Can you show the complete code?

Comment: Don't forget `$.getScript()` is async, it could be your issue. I said 'could' because i don't really understand what your demonstartion is supposed to show...

Comment: 5 works on stackoverflow for me

Comment: @Stapal, the issue is that function is not defined so can't use it at all. But simple sample code is on the http://powercle.linuxpl.eu/js/pdfmake_browserified3.html page - just click view source.

Comment: @Maxx, ah! bad example - try to run it on e.g. http://www.onet.pl/ site.

Comment: @A. Wolff, it's not async issue as I can wait for long and still it doesn't get loaded.

Comment: Have you tried using done()/fail() to see if some error ocurred? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/#handling-errors

Comment: @Haroldo_OK, yes, it all finishes correctly. No errors, 200, success.

Comment: Check `window.require`. Your library is not globaly defined if using amd

Comment: after `getScript` try `require(['//powercle.linuxpl.eu/js/pdfmake-browserified.min.js'], function(createPdf) { /* do something */ });`. Works on onet.pl

Comment: @Maxx thank you! Very helpful! I think you accurately found what my issue is. I actually was not aware of AMD approach to date (the website I do JS work is not owned by me so I do only client level enchancements) so reading about it now.